# How to add jQuery / HTML to Django Model Forms?

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to integrate conditionize.js (as shown in [this example](http://codepen.io/renvrant/pen/ogeeBY)) with my Django Model form. Since the template just is just like this:

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

there is no way to add all the HTML in that example. I found that you can add a class to the forms in forms.py like this:

```
'month': MonthYearWidget(attrs={'class': 'monthfieldclass'})
```

and add all the css in that class, but I'm not sure how to add all the other stuff in the HTML such as 'data-cond-option' and input type, to make the jQuery work.

I also found the [Django Widget Tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks) library, but I'm not sure how to make it run alongside django-crispy-forms, so though I understand it's better not to mix up backend and frontend logic, I'm stuck with looking for a way to add all the stuff from the html to the form somewhere.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own template tag. You can find inspiration in the Django widget tweaks for sure: https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks/blob/master/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py

For example, you can write tag to add html attribute to any element:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def add_attr(element, attr, value):
    result = element.replace('>', ' %s="%s">' % (attr, value), 1)
return mark_safe(result)
```

which appends the desired html attribute with its value to the end of the html element. This is just basic example and doesn't handle extending css classes etc, you might need a more sophisticated approach using regexes for handling all the cases.

then in your template you can use it

```
{{ form|add_attr|crispy }}
```

(maybe switch of the tags will be needed)